# Remove the $0$s in the sum of a sequence with infinitely many $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, summation, random-variables, expected-value

Let $x_n\in \Bbb R$. $y_n$ is a sequence constructed by inserting $0$ between terms of $x_n$. e.g $x_n:1,2,3,4...., y_n:1,0,2,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,5...$.

It is intuitively obvious that $\sum x_n$ converges iff $\sum y_n$ converges with $\sum x_n=\sum y_n$. As the $0$ does not contribute to the sum. However, I got stuck writing down the formal proof as a verification.

I am trying to use the statistical language to formally formulate the statement: let $X$ be a discrete random variable on the sample space $S$, if $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ contains all the values of $X$, then $E[X]=\sum x_nP(X=x_n)$. Here I defind the expected value $E[X]$ as $\sum y_i$ where $y_i$ are all the distinct values of $X$ and $P[X=x_n]:=P\{s\in S:X(s)=x_n\}$.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the number of zeros between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ as $z_{i+1}$. Let $r_n=\sum_{i=2}^{n}z_i$. $r_1$ is defined to be $0$. Let $s_n=n+r_n$. Then $$x_n=y_{s_n}.$$

Suppose $\sum x_n$ convreges. Then we know that sequence of its partial functions satisfies the Cauchy condition. i.e. For $\epsilon>0$, $\exists N$ such that for all $m>n>N$, we have $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^mx_i-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right|=\left|\sum_{i=n+1}^mx_i\right|\le\epsilon.$$ From this we can show that sequence of partial functions of $\sum y_n$ satisifes the Cauchy condition. Note that for any $m>n$ $$\left|\sum_{i={n+1}}^m y_i\right|=\left|\sum_{j\in J_{nm}}x_j\right|$$ where $J_{nm}=\{j\mid n< s_j\le m\}$. So for any $m>n>s_N$, $\inf J_{nm}>N$, and then $\left|\sum_{j\in J_{nm}}x_j\right|\le\epsilon$. Thus given $\epsilon>0$, we have found an integer, $s_N$, such that for any $m>n>s_N$, $\left|\sum_{i={n+1}}^m y_i\right|<\epsilon$. Hence the sequence of partial sums of $\sum y_n$ is Cauchy, which implies it converges.

I am sure you can prove the opposite direction.